How to get a file security descriptor by its handle in WinDBG kernel mode?
I have a handle associated with some file and I need to get its security descriptor in WinDbg kernel mode, but I cannot find it anywhere.
Here is the output of !handle command:
WINDBG>!handle 0x9c

PROCESS ffffd20753ab2080
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0900    Peb: 10f583c000  ParentCid: 069c
    DirBase: 19874f000  ObjectTable: ffff8f0f4c2ac840  HandleCount:  41.
    Image: CreateFileTests.exe

Handle table at ffff8f0f4c2ac840 with 41 entries in use

009c: Object: ffffd20750657b40  GrantedAccess: 00120089 (Protected) Entry: ffff8f0f4b7fe270
Object: ffffd20750657b40  Type: (ffffca02924f37a0) File
    ObjectHeader: ffffd20750657b10 (new version)
        HandleCount: 1 PointerCount: 32767
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \TEST\test.txt {HarddiskVolume3}

Displaying the object header (ffffd20750657b10):
WINDBG>dt nt!_OBJECT_HEADER ffffd20750657b10
   +0x000 PointerCount     : 0n32767
   +0x008 HandleCount      : 0n1
   +0x008 NextToFree       : 0x00000000`00000001 Void
   +0x010 Lock             : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x018 TypeIndex        : 0x65 'e'
   +0x019 TraceFlags       : 0 ''
   +0x019 DbgRefTrace      : 0y0
   +0x019 DbgTracePermanent : 0y0
   +0x01a InfoMask         : 0x4c 'L'
   +0x01b Flags            : 0 ''
   +0x01b NewObject        : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelObject     : 0y0
   +0x01b KernelOnlyAccess : 0y0
   +0x01b ExclusiveObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b PermanentObject  : 0y0
   +0x01b DefaultSecurityQuota : 0y0
   +0x01b SingleHandleEntry : 0y0
   +0x01b DeletedInline    : 0y0
   +0x01c Reserved         : 0
   +0x020 ObjectCreateInfo : 0xfffff800`84453ac0 _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION
   +0x020 QuotaBlockCharged : 0xfffff800`84453ac0 Void
   +0x028 SecurityDescriptor : (null) 
   +0x030 Body             : _QUAD

As you can see, the SecurityDescriptor field is null:
+0x028 SecurityDescriptor : (null) 

I tried to get it from _FILE_OBJECT->FsContext, _OBJECT_CREATE_INFORMATION->SecurityDescriptor with the same result.
SysInternals Process Explorer also cannot access file security descriptors from the Handles tab.
It's not a file specific issue because I can view the security attributes in File Explorer, but that's not what I need.
So the question is:
Is there any way to get the security descriptor of a file by its handle in kernel mode debugger?

Have you checked the output of !fileobj ffffd20750657b40 iirc it should show the granted access if thats what you mean. Or clicking the handlecount dml link also performs the same action iirc
